# tomcat 7 store session in redis

Tags: tomcat, redis

i try to us this project https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager
for store sessions in redis. 
*jedis-2.5.1* and *commons-pool-2* are in **tomcat/lib**
but it is also reqiure `org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool$Config`
when i put it(*commons-pool-1.6.jar*) in lib directory, **tomcat** throw exception `Type 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig'  is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool$Config'`

can smbd help?

Comment: the problem is resolved. i just download project from github, fix dependencies (jedis, tomcat versions), build it and all is ok. I hope it's help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git pull the lastest coede,modify build.gradle file

```
   dependencies {
      compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '7.0.54'
      compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '2.5.1'
   }
```

gradle  jar